# All partions deleted accidently and I lost all my very very important data

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, data-recovery, testdisk

I was using windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 on my machine I had to update my ubuntu so I decided to remove windows 7 and install ubuntu 15.10 while installation I was asked to remove the windows with warning I thought I would only delete windows partition like C drive but it removed all the partitions and create one partition and installed ubuntu on that. I read about testdisk its quite interesting software can I use it in my case do remember I have only one partition and Ubuntu is installed on it how can I get my data back which was saved on E drive of windows can some please help me out and I do not have external hard at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testdisk did the trick for me but I lost some data just because I installed ubuntu and it and the data was overwritten but I got my 90% of my most important data. I follow [this](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

First thing: **Power the computer down**!

Any attempt to write to the hard disk may overwrite the data you need to recover -- and Ubuntu (as with most operating systems) writes swap data continually, as well as log files, etc. in the root and home partition(s).

Others may be able to offer a method to recreate your partitions without loss of data; I don't know any reliable way to do that for file systems newer than FAT16.  But, you may only get one try (because rewriting the partition table and formatting the partitions will overwrite some data), so don't start that process until you have a proven method in hand.

The *easiest* way to get your data back would be to remove the hard disk from the machine and take it to a computer repair center for data recovery (or take the whole computer in).  That will be expensive, but if the data is that important, it may be worth doing.

Answer (score 2):

There are some software for data recovery.
I personally used "UFS Explorer Personal Recovery" a few years ago, and it worked. It is not expensive, and saved me a lot of data.

But first, **do not use your computer**. You have to put the disk in another working computer to be able to analyze and recover it.
Each boot and run will write data on disk, potentially erasing your data.